# Should I put separate functionality into multiple then callbacks?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, promise

The following code works but I am looking for ways to improve this. I want to make sure the API calls are handled correctly through the use of promises.

```
doSomething1(resp) {
  if (resp) {
    // Some code here
  } else {
    // Error handling
  }
}

doSomething2(resp) {
  // Some code here
}

fetchData() {
  apiFunctionOne(prop1, prop2)
    .then(resp => {
      this.doSomething1(resp);
      return resp;
    })
    .then(resp => {
      this.doSomething2(resp);
      return resp;
    })
    .then(resp => {
      this.doSomething3(resp);
    })
    .catch(this.errorHandling);
}

doSomething4(resp) {
  if (resp) {
    // Some code here
  } else {
    // Error handling
  }
}

doSomething3(resp) {
  apiFunctionTwo(prop1, prop2)
    .then(this.doSomething4)
    .then(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    })
    .catch(this.errorHandling);
}
```

Is it best to put each function in a separate `then` statements or within one `then` statement?
Are there any improvements I can make with my code?

Comment: Do the other `doSomethingXX` functions return promises? Your `doSomething3` function seems like it _should_ in which case you'd remve the `.catch` from in there and do `return this.doSomething3(resp)`. If they don't do async stuff, splitting them up does nothing useful.

Comment: Only the `doSomething3` function. It depends on the response from `apiFunctionOne`. The others are just setting state values.

Comment: My motto is to place all synchronous code depending on the resolution of the promise under a single `.then` stage. When you come to a point that there is a need for another asynchronous call then return a promise from that `then` stage and it's now time to handle it's results at the next `then` stage. Reminder... `thens` are not there to separate synchronous tasks but to eliminate the callback hell.

Answer (score 2):

Unless they're doing something async and you're returning a new promise, it just makes more more syntax clutter IMO: better to put all the synchronous code into its own block.

```
apiFunctionOne(prop1, prop2)
  .then(resp => {
  this.doSomething1(resp);
  this.doSomething2(resp);
  this.doSomething3(resp);
  return resp;
})
```